# Updating apache tomcat webapp doesn't take effect

Tags: tomcat

i have tomcat webapp displaying a message "It is advisable to enable the 'TFTP Encrypted Config' option..." and i need to change it.
i searched for the file containing this message text and i found it in /usr/local/thirdparty/apache-tomcat-7.0.100/work/Catalina/localhost/cmplatform/loader/resource/ApplicationResources.properties
i updated the text to "You MUST enable the 'TFTP Encrypted Config'" then i restarted tomcat service and clear browser cache but i still see the old text message not the updated one.
is there anything else i should do?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from tomcat docs: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.1-doc/introduction.html

> "**work directory** that contains temporary working directories for the
> deployed web applications."

So each time you restart tomcat, the files of your web application get processed again and put under work directory.

You need to edit the original file (e.g. the one that is under CATALINA_HOME/webapps/cmplatform/...)

Comment: thx for your answer. i checked the file i updated after restarting tomcat service and the change i made is still there. the desired text to be updated only exist under the path i mentioned.

Comment: According to this https://lists.apache.org/thread/nbfqz92m3738353dmpzmp6sopmzcpj6m the ApplicationResources.properties may even be (among other possible locations) bundled inside a jar (example myapp/WEB-INF/lib/myjar.jar)
Try to check if your properties file is defined elsewhere other than the tomcat work directory